# Open new webpage with currently open site using JavaScript bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, redirect, bookmarklet

I am trying to create a JavaScript bookmarklet.
Basically, first I will go to `site1.com`, I will then click on the bookmarklet and it will take the URL of the site1.com, and open `site2.com/go.php?go=site1.com`

So, the JavaScript needs to add `site1.com` to `site2.com/go.php?go=` and then open the webpage at `site2.com/go.php?go=site1.com`

Comment: you might need to inject a link on site1, since the browser will block window.open() calls from outside the tab (like bookmarklets). then you just pass `location.host`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bookmarklet will do exactly what you’re asking for:

```
javascript:window.location='http://site2.com/go.php?go='+escape(window.location.hostname);
```

The potential problem with that bookmarklet is that it will send you to
`http://site2.com/go.php?go=site1.com` whether you’re coming from `https://site1.com/secret.html?query=etc` or `http://site1.com`. That is, no matter where on `site1.com` you are when you click the bookmarklet, it will still send you to `http://site2.com/go.php?go=site1.com`.

---

So what I suspect you might want instead is:

```
javascript:window.location='http://site2.com/go.php?go='+escape(window.location);
```

This will allow the query string to show exactly where you were on `site1.com` when you clicked the bookmarklet, plus it includes the URI scheme (the `http://` or `https://` parts of the `site1.com` address). Using the same two examples respectively, this bookmarklet would send you to `http://site2.com/go.php?go=https://site1.com/secret.html?query=etc`¹ and `http://site2.com/go.php?go=http://site1.com/`.²

---

1. It will actually percent-encode the `site1.com` address and send you to `http://site2.com/go.php?go=https%3A//site1.com/secret.html%3Fquery%3Detc` because the `site1.com` address contains several [characters that don’t travel well as URI fragments unless encoded](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding#wiki-document-head).
2. Actually to `http://site2.com/go.php?go=http%3A//site1.com/` for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i needed.